# C# equivalent of python's struct.pack

Tags: c#, binary, struct, bit-packing

Is there a library for C# that allows similar functionality to python's `struct` from the [standard library](http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html)?

One can emulate the struct library quite closely with real aligned structs. But I didn't find yet any way to directly control the endianess in C#'s structs (the C#'s structs seems to be geared more towards COM interop, and less toward general purpose binary packing).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The closest equivalent would probably be to use [`BinaryWriter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binarywriter.aspx) writing into a [`MemoryStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.aspx), or [`BitConverter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.aspx) for a one-off conversion of a single value into a byte array.

If you want to control the endianness of that, you can use my EndianBinaryWriter/EndianBitConverter from [MiscUtil](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/miscutil). One extra feature of my `EndianBitConverter` is that you can convert into a specific portion of an existing array, which would help you if you wanted to port `struct.pack` yourself.