# Struct.Pack Equivalent in C#?

Tags: c#, python

I'm building a C# client that connects to a render application and failing dismally!
I narrowed the problem down by dissecting a python client that does work to this line:

```
def Startclient_Click(self, sender, e):
     try:
         s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
         s.connect((host, int(port)))
         message =  b'message "Render"'
         msg = struct.pack('<l',len(message))+struct.pack('<l',0)+message
         #print(msg)
         s.sendall(msg)
         data = s.recv(1024)

         data.decode("utf-8")
         self.datatxt.Text ="data: " +str(data)
         s.close()

         return
     except:
         self.datatxt.Text ="No Server Connection"
         return
```

What would the equivalent be in C#?
From my understanding it needs 8 bytes before the message.

Comment: the first argument tells it which way to pack that is your most likely problem... I think that(`'<l'`) means the lsb is on the far left... but I could easily be wrong

Comment: For additional reference - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1818242/c-sharp-equivalent-of-pythons-struct-pack

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[struct.pack](http://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html) takes a format followed by a series of values that will be packed according to the format. In your question you call:

```
struct.pack('<l', len(message))+struct.pack('<l',0)+message
```

Which is saying "Pack the length of this message as a little-endian long followed by a zero packed as a little-endian long followed by appending the rest of my message".

When you approach this kind of problem in C# we unfortunately do not have a direct port of struct.pack. Your closest equivalent would be to use either a [BitConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.aspx) for one-off conversions like:

```
BitConverter.GetBytes((long)message.length) + BitConverter.GetBytes(0l) + message
```

or use a [BinaryWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binarywriter.aspx) into a [MemoryStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.aspx). This brings yet another problem though which is that you cannot control the endian-ness using these tools. They expose "IsLittleEndian" so you know how they are acting but you cannot alter it.

Jon Skeet however is on the case - his [MiscUtils](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/miscutil/) library contains a LittleEndianBitConverter (MiscUtil.Conversion.LittleEndianBitConverter) that you can use or an EndianBinaryWriter should you go the Writer/MemoryStream route. So putting it all together, reference the MiscUtil library and use something like:

```
var bytes = new List<byte[]>(new[]
    {
        LittleEndianBitConverter.GetBytes(message.LongLength), 
        LittleEndianBitConverter.GetBytes(0l), 
        message
    });

var msg = new byte[bytes.Sum(barray => barray.LongLength)];
int offset = 0;
foreach (var bArray in bytes)
{
    System.Buffer.BlockCopy(bArray, 0, msg, offset, bArray.Length);
    offset = bArray.Length;
}
```

The code is untested but should give you a reasonable starting point. It's assuming that your message is already a byte array and that msg is the array you want to return. We use System.Buffer.BlockCopy as it's the most efficient copy method for primitive types.

* EDIT ***

I've taken the example in the question and mocked up a quick script in [IDEOne](http://ideone.com/) for the [Python code](http://ideone.com/UQQiNi) and its [equivalent in C#](http://ideone.com/Sahh4Q). The kicker here is that the `Struct.Pack('<l', 0)` call ignores the byte and does not add it to the output which may be what's tripping you up. This was causing the output to be 8 bytes too long.

Those scripts should point you in the right direction. If you're still having trouble can you post the code that you've tried.

For reference, the finished code in Python:

```
import struct
message =  b'message "Render"'
msg = struct.pack('<l',len(message)) + struct.pack('<l',0) + message
print(":".join("{0:x}".format(ord(c)) for c in msg))
```

And in C#:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using MiscUtil.Conversion;

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var message = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("message \"Render\"");

            var lenc = new LittleEndianBitConverter();

            var bytes = new List<byte[]>(new[]
            {
                lenc.GetBytes(message.LongLength),
                message
            });

            var msg = new byte[bytes.Sum(barray => barray.LongLength)];
            int offset = 0;
            foreach (var bArray in bytes)
            {
                Buffer.BlockCopy(bArray, 0, msg, offset, bArray.Length);
                offset = bArray.Length;
            }

            Console.WriteLine(BitConverter.ToString(msg).Replace("-", ":"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'll get back to you as soon as I get chance to give it a try :)

Comment: I'm still having problems sadly, I've updated my original post with the working wpf ironpython version, to be honest I think its going to involve someone testing the c# version with Thea render and I don't expect anyone to download a 100meg app that they'll never use. At least I have the python one to do some prototyping with until I find the answer :)

Comment: @NigeC, What can be the equivalent of  `(origsize, cmpsize, ) = unpack('<LL', catrec)` in C#