# Is there a equivalent of python's struct.pack in C#?

Tags: c#, python, bitconverter, struct.pack

Is there a more or less equivalent of Pythons' struct pack in C# ?
What i basically need to do is 'rewriting' a part of a python-script in C#. The following functions are required to prepare some text, so that it can be send via a socket...

```
def PrepString(text):
return struct.pack('>h', len(text)) + text.encode('utf_16_be')

def PrepStringMed(text):
return struct.pack('>h', len(text)) + '\x00' + '\x00'.join(list(text))

def PrepStringOld(text):
msg = '\x00' + '\x00'.join(list(text))
return chr(len(text)) + msg
```

I already tried some methods with some MemoryStream etc. but the remoteapplication (local server) yust spammed the log with errors...
It would be nice to get this working with "Onboard"-resources of VS, yust for simplicity and whenever I  would need that e.g  at work, i would know how to solve it without extra-libraries

Comment: Can you explain what that code does? I'm not familiar with Python.

Comment: @Selman22 Damn, clicked on the wrong question. It's a duplicate of: [Struct.Pack Equivalent in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19337056/struct-pack-equivalent-in-c-sharp)

Comment: @Bakuriu Sorry, if you think so... But the functions im mean are different. Also the "accepted" answer uses some additional classes created by the user, what I am not supposed/allowed to use

Comment: There may be a more direct translation, but I think you're looking for something along the lines of the BinaryWriter class (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binarywriter(v=vs.110).aspx).  You'll need to take care of endianness yourself though.